# Using firebreath plugin on Mac

Tags: macos, firebreath, browser-plugin

I have developed a test plugin using FireBreath on Visual Studio 2010. I could make it work on windows by registering the output dll...

Now I would like to check whether this plugin works on Mac. I have no idea about this..

Do I need to create plugin for Mac using XCode or I can use the same dll?

Any of your help is much appreciated.. This question may seem to be silly to some of you. But I am new to C++ and plugin...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a DLL is windows-only.  To build a plugin on Mac, you need xcode installed on your mac, the firebreath codebase, and the project directory (*not* the build/ directory) for your plugin.

Then follow the instructions on [Building on Mac OS](http://www.firebreath.org/x/AoAO) on the firebreath website.